# Does $Ax+Bx=\lambda x$ imply $\langle Ax ,x \rangle + \langle Bx, x \rangle=\langle\lambda x, x \rangle$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $A$ and $B$ be real matrices. Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A+B$. Let $x$ be a corresponding eigenvector

Then $Ax+ Bx= \lambda x$.

My question is:

Is it valid to take the inner product on both side of the equation here?

Like $ \langle Ax ,x \rangle + \langle Bx, x \rangle = \langle \lambda x, x \rangle $. Is this valid?

In general, can we always take the inner product on both sides of an equation?

Thanks!

Comment: yes, 'cuz inner product is linear in each slot

Comment: Linearity is useful to break apart the inner product.  But, at its heart, the OP's question is much more primitive.  Basically asking if I have an equation, can I apply the same functional to both sides.  I can do this for nonlinear functionals as well.  For example, $\cos(Ax+By) = \cos(\lambda x)$, where cosine is elementwise.  Note the the functional in your example is $f(x) = <\cdot,x>$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. As inner product is additive in each  component. But you have to be careful while dealing with homogeneity as inner product is conjugate linear. But in real inner product it's linear in both components i.e a real inner product is a bilinear map.

Here we only need additivity, so it's fine for any inner product space.

$\langle \lambda x,x\rangle= \langle Ax+ Bx,x
 \rangle=\langle Ax, x\rangle+\langle Bx,x
 \rangle$